# I keep on getting this error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Whenever I try to append the f-string to the list, I always get back this error:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message

The variable "queue" is empty.

However, when I print the f-string, it shows the user id and the message

```
@client.command(name='addqueue', pass_context=True)
async def addqueue(ctx,*,reason:str):
queue=[]
queue = queue.append(f'{ctx.author.send}: {reason}')
print(f'{ctx.author.id}: {reason}\n')
await ctx.channel.send(embed=queue)
```

I am not sure how to procede with this.

Answer (score 0):

`queue.append` modifies `queue` in-place and returns `None`. Thus, after `queue = queue.append(...)`, `queue` is `None`.

You should just `append` without assigning, like this:

```
queue=[]
queue.append(f'{ctx.author.send}: {reason}')
```

BTW, you can use a list literal instead of `append`ing to an empty list:

```
queue = [f'{ctx.author.send}: {reason}']
```

Comment: I get this error using your first solution: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_dict'. I'm going to try to other one.

Comment: I get the same error in the second one too.

Comment: @YashSharma, according to the documentation, [the `embed` argument](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send) should be of type [`Embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed), not a list. The error in the original post happens because `embed` is `None`. Converting the `queue` list to `Embed` is a different question, though. Judging by the error message, it's not possible to simply `embed` a list.

Answer (score 0):

On the 2nd declaration of queue, `queue = queue.append()` the append functions return None thus you'll end up setting `ctx.send(embed=None)`, which is wrong as discord doesn't allow you to send empty messages.
As you have done you can't pass python default object types to `embed` parameter in `ctx.send()`, Only Embed objects can be assigned to it.

To create Embed objects kindly refer [`discord.Embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Embed) and before doing something as complicated as creating a bot kindly learn python basics by doing smaller (less complicated) projects to understand the language.